# node.io issues with built in modules

Tags: node.js, node.io

So I can run a js file like

```
$ node file.js
```

with node.io inside the file doing things.
but if i go to the command line and try to type in a built in module like it shows at https://www.npmjs.org/package/node.io

```
$ node.io query "http://www.reddit.com/" a.title
```

I just get back -bash: node.io: command not found

This is probably something incredibly stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just means that node.io is not installed or if installed is not available in $PATH.

You can install it using the following command.

```
$ npm install -g node.io
```

Comment: And to help understand how `npm` works this is still valid http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/